# How to modify moderation alert settings for Community Server?

Tags: community-server

How can I setup administrator alerts in Community Server for things like - new threads, new posts, new users, etc?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question might receive more response here at the [Community Server Forums](http://dev.communityserver.com/).